# Find current base of output stream

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

Is it possible, when overloading the `<<` operator to write to an output stream, to get what numeric base this stream is currently in? E.g. if `std::hex` was called before calling my overloaded operator, can I find out if the stream is currently in "hex mode"?

Comment: You do it by calling [`std::ostream::flags()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags), rather then via an IO manipulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay after digging a little about how this base change actually works, I found out that there are basically only these 3 bases to choose from (`std::dec`, `std::oct`, `std::hex`). Calling `std::setbase()` with a value other than `10`, `8` or `16` simply defaults to dec.

As Paul Sanders figured out one can get the current flags via `std::ostream::flags()` and then `&` those with the basefield:

`(std::ostream::flags() & std::ios_base::<base>` is `0` if it's not the current base, and its something else if it is.